# Copy of a file form PaaS to PaaS with Azure Data Management Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As you know, the Data Management Gateway (for Data Factory) is a software that connects On Premise or IaaS data sources to cloud services.
DMG is able to have an IaaS server (SQL, MySQL, Share file, …) as an endpoint to a Data Factory pipeline.

But I would like to know if it's possible to implement the copy of a file from Azure Blob Storage (PaaS) to the Data Lake Storage (PaaS) through the Data Management Gateway?

Kr,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

That scenario would actually leverage the Azure Integration Runtime (new name for the DMG) to copy between Azure cloud resources. It's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview